# Is it safe ? Is it scam or real?

Tags: bank-account, scams, sugar-daddy

I started talking to this sugar daddy for a week. But we barely talk much... he said he would help me with ALL my bills. He only wants to see me 1-2 a month. I told him my bills. And he said he’ll put his credit card in my account in autopay to my phone bills. I don’t have credit card so he asked my username and password so he could check deposit money into my bank account...I know he helped me but I’m still hesitant to give out my bank info but maybe he’s serious in helping ? He’s not pressuring me or keep hitting me up about it.

Comment: Have you met him in real life, even once?

Comment: Do you know you don't need username and password to send people money?

Comment: He doesn't need your bank username and password to send you money. If he wants to initiate a bank transfer, that can be done without giving out your login details.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at some of the related questions over in the right side bar. You'll see that this is a scam, and the exact same question comes up over, and over, and over again.

**It's a scam! Change your password, and notify your bank ASAP.**

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely a scam! Don’t do it! If he legitimately wants to help you, there’s other ways he can without knowing your banking information. Let’s assume his intentions are pure, set up alternative payment methods like PayPal, or accepting checks.

Don’t give him any personal banking information. People like this are con-artists they’ll convince you that their intention is only good, then steal everything you have, never to be seen again. Be very careful!